# fatal error: Box2D.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, box2d

I have developed a game in xcode using cocos2d-x 2.2.3 and box2d. Now i am trying to port from ios to android. However i am getting the following error while build through terminal.

```
In file included from jni/../../Classes/LevelScene.cpp:1:0:
jni/../../Classes/LevelScene.h:6:19: fatal error: Box2D.h: No such file or 
directory
compilation terminated.
 make: ***
[obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/LevelScene.o] Error  1
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied the files which is in box2d folder and placed in classes folder. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to allow CMake to find the directory. In the `CMakeLists.txt` file, use it like this:
`set(Box2D_SOURCE_DIR "/path/to/your/folder/liquidfun-1.1.0/liquidfun/Box2D")`
`include_directories (${Box2D_SOURCE_DIR})`
You could also set the directory relatively:
`set(Box2D_SOURCE_DIR "..")`